# A question about the definition of reduced Gröbner basis

Tags: polynomials, definition, groebner-basis

I am reading Professor Sturmfels's article [What Is...a Gröbner Basis?](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/200510/what-is.pdf) In the definition of reduced Gröbner basis, I met a term `trailing term` of a polynomial. I do not konw what does it exactly mean. Can anyone give me some detail? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Trailing term, in this context, means any term except the leading term (with respect to the chosen admissable ordering). Condition (3) says that to turn a Gröbner basis into a reduced Gröbner basis you also have to cancel all terms in all elements of the Gröbner basis (by subtracting a suitable multiple of one of the other elements) when possible (i.e., if it indeed is a multiple of the leading term of one of the other elements).